# Google Analytics Sending offline events Landing page not set

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

we are sending offline conversions (calls) to Analytics using the measurement protocol, we are using GTM to collect the CID of the user, which also has the GA UA code.

We are sending events fine, that is working, but we are getting landing page (not set) on everything, I've tried creating a pageview with custom CID values, that doesn't seem to work.

If I do Audience -> User Explorer, I can see the CID and track that user through the pages to the event.

```
v=1
&t=event
&tid=UA-xxxx-xx
&cid=111.111
&ec=event
&el=Some%20Event%20Label
&ea=Some%20Event%20Action
&cs=google
&cm=cpc
&gclid=somevalue
&ds=call
&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somewebsite
&dh=somewebsite
&dp=Some%20Conversion
&dt=Some%20Page%20about%20Call
&z=1234
&ni=1
```

How do we get see/set what landing page has triggered the event, we are using Behaviour -> Site Content -> Landing Pages and looking at the goals on the right.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a pageview before (with same cid) then you can send an event to that page.

Comment: Thanks Michele, will give it another go with a pageview, we did try that, but that came through with 'not set' also, is there a way if sending a page view to send it as a non-interaction so it won't inflate page views?

Comment: Some time ago I did some tests with non-interactive pageviews, here you find the results: https://www.analyticstraps.com/visualizzazioni-di-pagina-non-interattive-piu-o-meno/ Anyway, have you tried to start the event as interactive?

Comment: Interesting read thank you for sharing, will do some more testing.

Comment: Non-interaction pageview really helps. Thanks so much.